# Arduino - How to convert Hex byte into its ASCII char equivalent?

Tags: c++, arduino, char, hex

Let's say I have a hex byte `uint8_t my_hex = 0x50` that needs to be converted to its ASCII text equivalent which would be 'P'.

I've tried using the Arduino library's built-in String object:

```
uint8_t my_hex = 0x50;
String my_char = String(my_hex) //output 80
```

But it seems to output its decimal equivalent in string form. I really need to convert it to its text/character equivalent.

Comment: You don't have to convert anything, aside maybe assigning to a plain `char`

Comment: `char my_hex = 0x50;`

Answer (score 2):

`my_hex` already contains the ASCII character value.  Just type-cast it to a `char`, eg:

```cpp
uint8_t my_hex = 0x50;
String my_char = String((char)my_hex) //output "P"
```